# Accessing a property of a pointer in a struct

Tags: c++, arrays, object, pointers, properties

First of I have 2 Classes in 2 files (both .h and .cpp files), *Create.h* and *AI.h*.

Create.h has this struct in it:

```
public:
    struct Cell
        {
            int row;
                int column;
            vector<Cell*> neighbors;
            State state;
        };
```

Here is the enum class State (stored in the Create.h file):

```
enum class State : char
{
     visited,
     empty
};
```

In AI.h I have a stack and a Create object like this:

```
private:
    deque<Create::Cell*> path;
    Create obj;
```

In AI.cpp there is an instance called *obj* which contains a 2D array of Cell where every Cell has row, column, state and neighbors set appropriately.

Constructor:

```
AI::AI(Create createObj)
: obj(createObj)
{
    start = &obj.array[1][1];
}
```

I also have a function like this which starts with `start` as an argument:

```
void AI::Function(Create::Cell* cell)
{
    path.push_back(cell);
    cell->state = State::visited;

    while (expression)
    {
        cell = path.back();
        cell->state = State::visited;

        for (int i = 0; i < cell->neighbors.size(); i++)
        {
            if (cell->neighbors[i]->state == State::empty)
            {
                path.push_back(cell->neighbors[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So basically the cell in the path stack starts by pointing to the obj.array[1][1] and sets it correctly (I have confirmed that it actually points where I want it to) but when I retrieve a cell from the stack it doesn't point to the obj.array.

What I am trying to do is to set the state of the neighbors of each cell but I manage to set the state on the *path* stack, on the cell itself but NOT on the array inside the obj instance.

What I definitely can do and it works is set the obj.array[i][j] under the cell like this:

```
cell = path.back();
cell->state = State::visited;
obj.array[cell->row][cell->column].state = State::visited;
```

What I wanted to know is if there is a way (through pointers I presume) to make the obj.array Cell element know that it's being set by the *cell->state = State::visited;*

Comment: If I understand this properly then your problem will be solved if the path cell pointers point to the obj array. So I guess the question is how you are adding the cell pointers to the path, and is there any reason why they shouldn't point to the obj array?

Comment: The cell pointers are added through this `path.push_back(cell);` (I am not sure if that is your question though). I don't think there would be a problem to make them point to the obj.array but how would I do that? Making the path a pointer-to-pointer Cell deque? Because I am pretty sure I tried that earlier and I had a lot of problems with it.

Comment: So `path` is.... what ? a `std::deque< Create::Cell* >` ? And is it in your wheelhouse to use `std::shared_ptr<Create::Cell>` for all of this and stop the insanity of the raw-pointer extravaganza?

Comment: It's not completely clear what you're trying to do. Where is `obj.array` defined?

Comment: @MadisonScodelario The question is where does the cell pointer come from in `path.push_back(cell);`? I'm not suggesting that you change your data structures, just that you make `cell` point to the obj array (instead of wherever it's pointing now).

Comment: @WhozCraig `path` is a `std::deque< Create::Cell* >`. The problem is I have never used `shared_ptr` so for now at least I'm trying to find the pointer way and maybe later I'll try using it.

Comment: @patchwork obj.array is actually defined in the constructor as a copy of an instance from `Create`. The AI constructor takes as argument an object from `Create` and he copies it to the obj in the AI. It is defined as a private Create object (edited in).

Comment: @MadisonScodelario this seems to be the heart of the problem, you are copying Cell objects when (at least in scenario above) you shouldn't be copying Cell objects. But it's hard to tell what the best thing to do is from the snippetts of code give so far.

Comment: @john I definitely need to copy the object, I am editing in the AI constructor with some explanation on where path Cell is pointing

Comment: @MadisonScodelario OK well if that is the case then you seem to have contradictory requirements. I'm not sure what the solution is. Maybe the code you have currently is the best you can do.

Comment: I gave some more detail on where it points exactly according to the debugger and my goal.